# center element(with 50px margin) using transform translate

Tags: css, margin, center

I have an element positioned absolute with margin 50px so after setting left 50% and transform translate (-50%) element is not center because of margin.
Is there an option center element horizontally and keep the margin 50px and transform translate (-50%)

I have a @mixin theme-btn with margin 50px

```
.btn{
   @include theme-btn();
   &--uslugi{

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

}

Comment: Kind of weird positioning.Can you share your html and css code as well ?

Comment: you need to decide (1) either you center the element (margin is irrelevant) (2) apply margin (center is irrelevant). Having both is contradictory

Comment: `transform:translateX(calc(-50% - 50px));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a parent div to your div, for example:

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-in">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.box-in {
    margin: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```